# Find closest number in array to a number not in the array

Tags: java, arrays

The question as asked in the title has already been answered, but there are some constraints i am bound by that require a different solution.

The answer to finding the closest value in an array to a number:

```
     int myNumber = 490;
int distance = Math.abs(numbers[0] - myNumber);
int idx = 0;
     for(int c = 1; c < numbers.length; c++)
     {
          int cdistance = Math.abs(numbers[c] - myNumber);
          if(cdistance < distance)
          {
               idx = c;
               distance = cdistance;
          }
}
int theNumber = numbers[idx];
```

For some background on what makes my problem specific enough to ask:

My program takes in a PriorityQueue of hospital patients. There are 3 operating rooms, and the program will output the 8 hour(a work day) schedule for those 3 operating rooms, in addition my "postpone" array, containing patients that did not make the cut for that day. I have an array called roomCapacity which contains the remaining hours in each room. Heres where my problem is more specific than the title. The above answer uses the distances between each number and in my case picks the roomCapacity with the least distance(best fit). But there are times when the DIFFERENCE is -1. I realize the Math.abs ensures the DISTANCE is positive, but in this particular case I have no reason to use absolute value for the reason being an operation may not be scheduled in a room if the duration of the operation is longer than the capacity of the room. The DISTANCE(absolute value of the difference) must be greater than OR equal to zero. I've spent what I have decided counterproductive trying to find a solution, and would greatly appreciate some hints.

In a hurry to get this done i slapped the above code into my method, and only after using the debugger realized that I was placing patients in rooms whos capacities were less than the operations duration, but would be the best fit neglecting said constraint.

(EDIT)Specific question: How do I find the closest number in my roomCapacity array to a value(int d) using a similar approach to the one shown above, while taking into account the difference may not be less than 0?

(This is my first question, appologies for the ambiguity)

my method:

```
public int getBestRoom(int d)//int d = currentOperationDuration
{
     int roomNumber;
     /**
      *int distance = Math.abs(roomCapacity[0] - d);
      *int idx = 0;
      *for(int c = 1; c < 3; c++)
      *{
      *     int cdistance = Math.abs(roomCapacity[c] - d);
      *     if(cdistance < distance)
      *     {
      *          idx = c;
      *          distance = cdistance;
      *     }
      *roomNumber = idx;
      *}
      **/
return roomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a specific question, rather than "I dunno, do I need a hint?" If not, code review requests go on a different section of Stack Exchange.

Comment: "The DISTANCE(absolute value of the difference) must be greater than OR equal to zero." - Why don't you just check that in addition to `Math.abs()`? Simply check if `roomCapacity[c] - d >= 0`. Of course then you have to think about situations where you can't take any room, and maybe return -1 or something.

Comment: If there are no rooms that the current patient would fit into, my code wont even reach this point. Also i attempted trying to use >= 0 but resulted in excessive use of if statements and I am trying to avoid that, it got confusing and hard to keep track of what my code was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, remove all `Math.abs` and test for positive distances only:

```
int myNumber = 490;
int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int idx = 0;
for(int c = 0; c < numbers.length; c++)
{
    int cdistance = numbers[c] - myNumber;
    if (cdistance < distance && cdistance >= 0)
    {
        idx = c;
        distance = cdistance;
    }
}
int theNumber = numbers[idx];
```

Comment: This does not work. Consider myNumber = 4, and my array   roomCapacity{3,8,8}...the index i want my method to return would be 1, as it cannot fit in 0, and does not matter whether i place it in 1 or 2 as they are equal and the whole point is finding the best fit. Your solution places it in roomCapacity[0]

Comment: Still fails the same test case but did give me an idea which im too fried from today to investigate further so ill check tomorrow. Thanks